# XP Pro Ubuntu Install?

Tags: system-installation, system

My Computer currently has Windows XP Pro on it. Can I just download Ubuntu on top of it or must I format and make a clean install?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of options.

**If you want to use Ubuntu & Windows:**

You could use the [Wubi installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows). Note that this method works well with the current 12.04 LTS release, but won't work for 13.10. Also note that Ubuntu doesn't install in a true dual boot configuration using this method. Check the [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) for more detailed information.

**If you want a fresh clean install of Ubuntu:**

You could use something like the [pendrivelinux Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to make a bootable USB installer. You'll need to [download the appropriate ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) for the version of Ubuntu you want to install but this method also has no restrictions on version and you can easily install 13.10 if you desire.

Both would do the trick for you depending on what you want the end state to be.

Comment: Thanks.  Let me also ask you, when I install will I lose all my application programs that work in XP Pro?

Comment: If you use the Wubi method, Windows will still be available to boot into which means you'll still have access to your Windows programs. I would recommend backing up your system before doing any of these changes though just as a best practice. :)

Comment: Thank You Very Much Mat.  I will give it a try.  All the best.

Comment: More than happy to help! Accept the answer if you think it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu should allow you to allocate space for your Ubuntu partition when you install (side by side install) There are a fair amount guides available for setting up those partitions and GRUB too ( if necessary ). Pop that live cd in and take a tour!